# CSS grid auto column with additional div at every column

Tags: css

How do I add additional fixed width column in the grid column template. Lets say I have 12 columns in a container with auto width, and I wanted to add 12 more columns in between with fixed width.

This is what I tried but unable to figure out how to make the additional column as fixed width and rest columns are auto width in the same container and no wrap.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(25, 1fr);
}

.grid .col {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.additional-div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">7</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">8</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">9</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">10</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">11</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">12</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to use grid layout? It would be much easier using flexbox

Comment: Not necessary, do you mean, `display:flex`? yes, we can but it requires some manual adjustments. so if it is a grid then the number of columns can be adjusted automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you might want:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, min-content 1fr) min-content;
}

.grid .col {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.additional-div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">7</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">8</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">9</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">10</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">11</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">12</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
</div>
```

It would also be simpler to use flexbox to achieve the same layout:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.grid .col {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.additional-div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  flex: 0 0 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">7</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">8</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">9</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">10</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">11</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
  <div class="col">12</div>
  <div class="additional-div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to achieve. Perfect it works as expected 

Comment: Please help me understand what this is inside and outside the bracket. `min-content 1fr) min-content`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Hao Wu's answer, you can use this ruleset to make responsive your grid.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(24px, 1fr));
}
```

You can set the width of the fixed-size with the `24px` area and the `1fr` area will grow as your content size.

You should specify the width of the additional-div class within the `minmax` function, instead of its own ruleset.

```css
.additional-div {
  /* width: 24px; */
}
```

Comment: This is not working as expected, if you open and see in inspect element then it shows there are too many grid columns in the `.grid container`. I faced this issue when I tried on my own.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you want to use an explicit value and it's hard to control over your grid. You can try `auto-fit` and `min-content` instead of `auto-fill` like this; `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(24px, min-content));`